# Hangfire: Looks like the job was aborted

Tags: asp.net, background-process, hangfire

I have a Hangfire (with SqlServer for persistence) job which query some data from database. Then generate an Excel and sent it via Email to users.

I got below error message while processing the job:

**The job was aborted – it is processed by server XXXXX which is not in the active servers list for now. It will be retried automatically after invisibility timeout, but you can also re-queue or delete it manually.**

How to handle this? help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It's going to be case per case basis, you cant generalize the solution for this error. Each job that is queued that fails when the server goes offline, will be retried automatically and if the method invoked can be re executed without issues, you should be fine. Otherwise you will have to look into what your job does and checks to make sure duplicate work is not performed.

Comment: `Each job that is queued that fails when the server goes offline, will be retried automatically` - it does say so in docs but in reality sometimes it restarts, sometimes not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I was running a SQL server on different server and Application using dashboard UI on a different server. Problem was both servers had a system time gap of 1 minute. After syncing the time on both the servers issue got resolved.